# Residue for function $z/\sin^2 z$

Tags: complex-analysis

For integer $n$, I would like to find the residue at $n\pi $ of the function $f(z)=\dfrac{z}{\sin^2 z}$.

For $z=0$ the residue is just $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}zf(z)=1$.

For $z=n\pi$ where $n\neq 0$, the pole has order $2$. I write $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{(z-n\pi)^2}\cdot\dfrac{z(z-n\pi)^2}{\sin^2 z}$ The function $\dfrac{z(z-n\pi)^2}{\sin^2 z}$ should be holomorphic near $n\pi$, so I want to Taylor-expand it. But it has both numerator and denominator zero. What can I do?

Comment: Seems to me that you would have poles of second order instead of first. Perhaps if you compute accordingly you will find the answer. Need to think a bit more.

Comment: @Marc Yeah, usually the denominator is obvious functions like $(z-3)^2$, so the pole is order $2$. But here I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's better to use  $\large z = n\pi + \epsilon_{n}\,$.

Comment: @FelixMarin I'm not sure what you mean there. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $\;z=w-n\pi\;$ , so:

$$\frac{w-n\pi}{\sin^2(w-n\pi)}=\frac{w-n\pi}{\left((w-n\pi)-\frac{(w-n\pi)^3}6+\ldots\right)^2}=$$

$$=\frac1{(w-n\pi)\left(1-\frac{(w-n\pi)^2}6+\ldots\right)^2}=\frac1{w-n\pi}\left(\ldots+1+\frac{(w-n\pi)^2}6+\left(\frac{(w-n\pi)^2}6\right)^2+\ldots\right)$$

$$=\ldots+\frac1{(w-n\pi)}+\frac{w-n\pi}6+\ldots\implies\;\text{the residue thus is}\;\;1$$

The dots from the left indicate that there might be some terms $\;(z-n\pi)^{-k}\;,\;\;k>1\;$ there that come from the the elements with higher powers in the denominator of the right side of the first line and etc.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that to compute the residue, I should write $f(z)=\dfrac{a_{-1}}{z-n\pi}+\ldots$. But here you have $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}+\ldots$ (since $z=w-n\pi$)

Comment: No, I have $\;\frac1{\text{the variable minus}\; n\pi}\;$...what do we care how the variable is named?

Comment: Please read my comment carefully - it's not just about how the variable is named. But maybe you're still right, I don't know. But I don't think what you're doing follows the definition of the residue.

Comment: I really don't understand you, @MikaH. : you can either evaluate the residue *directly* at the pole $\;n\pi\;$ or else you can substitute and evaluate at the pole $\;0\;$...

Comment: For one thing, I think the pole as order $2$, not $1$ as your expansion is suggesting.

Comment: Well @Mika, no need "to think=in the sense of to believe". Just prove\disprove that$$\lim_{z\to n\pi}(z-n\pi)f(z)$$ is non-finite/finite. I think you might be surprised...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it should have order $1$ at zero, but still order $2$ at $n\pi$ where $n\neq 0$.

Comment: I think I'm already confused. I shall come back later to check this if you still have doubt because I'm already dizzy...

Comment: Before I go a last try: check that we *still* get the same residue, though.

Comment: Of course you were right: at $\;n\pi\;,\;\;n\neq 0\;$ the pole's order cannot be one...

Comment: So, after all this, you decide that the best option is to downvote the answer, @MikaH. ? Oh, well...

Comment: I didn't downvote it - maybe someone else did? Anyway, you're not following the residue definition as far as I know ...

Comment: Oh, yes I am @MikaH.: it is the coefficient of $\;(z-a)^{-1}\;$  in the Laurent series of the function around the pole $\;a\;$ , and if you think it is something else perhaps you should do a little checking.

Answer (score 0):

Expand $\sin(z)$ in a Taylor series at $z=n\pi$.  You shouldn't need very many terms before you should know what the pole's order is.